# Linux Solus: aircrack-ng not found

Tags: linux, aircrack-ng, solus

I'm using Solus version for linux (on Lenovo ThinkPad T61 if that is important), and when i tried to download aircrack-ng with the following commands, they returned error, saying that:

```
System error. Program terminated.
Repo item aircrack-ng not found
```

That happend after i tried to install this package using the "Package Installer" on my Solus, with this command:

```
1. sudo eopkg install aircrack-ng
```

I've tried to install this package manually, by downloading the tar.gz file, and extract his content to another folder, then, to open the folder, and type this command:

```
2. sudo eopkg it -c system.devel
```

But this time, it just tells me that there are no packages to install.

Also the `3. make` command, wasn't working, because I didn't found any Makefile inside the package itself.

I don't realy understand why it didnt found this package, when Solus using Linux as good as other systems does. so if you can help, Thank you

Comment: What are the "few commands" you used to try to download aircrack-ng?

Comment: @Wildcard I changed it. but it was the sudo eopkg commands, i searched for some alternatives for them, but i couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first try, *eopkg* package manager apparently hasn't found *aircrack-ng* in its repositories.
After a look at Package Management page in Solus Project wiki I found a link to a package list on [this section](https://wiki.solus-project.com/Package_Management#List_Repo.28s.29), then I downloaded [that link](https://packages.solus-project.com/shannon/eopkg-index.xml.xz) and I didn't found *aircrack-ng*.

#### Let's do the compilation ...

---

BEFORE STARTING:
Maybe you need to resolve some dependencies in order to make the installation of aircrack-ng in Solus (for more details read *INSTALLING* file in aircrack-ng package):
I think these mandatory and optional dependencies are already present in your system as you may find in [this page](https://git.solus-project.com/packages/) of Solus git repo.

**Mandatory deps:**

- libgcrypt `user@host:~$ sudo eopkg install libgcrypt`
- ethtool `user@host:~$ sudo eopkg install ethtool`
- libnl `user@host:~$ sudo eopkg install libnl`
- pkg-config `user@host:~$ sudo eopkg install pkg-config`

**Optional deps:**

- libpcre `user@host:~$ sudo eopkg install libpcre`
- sqlite3 `user@host:~$ sudo eopkg install sqlite3`

---

**Compiling and Installing ...**
 **1.** Get the source code download from [aircrack-ng official page](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/):
    `user@host:~$ wget http://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc4.tar.gz`
 **2.** Extract the content and enter in the directory:
    `user@host:~$ tar -xzf aircrack-ng-1.2-rc4.tar.gz`
    `user@host:~$ cd aircrack-ng-1.2-rc4`
 **3.** Now you simply type:
    `user@host:~$ make`
    `user@host:~$ make strip`
    `user@host:~$ sudo make install`

---

If a problem arrives, first look at https://trac.aircrack-ng.org/ticket/1671, or try to send an email to [a developer](http://trac.aircrack-ng.org/wiki/Team).

Comment: Wow man, huge thanks ! You realy saved me from switch to anouther linux 